# How can I compare encrypted password strings correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I have a basic html page with a username and password input boxes. Along with a login button. I am using `cryptojs` to try and compare encryption strings.

I believe my problem is because I'm randomly generating my key and iv. Do y'all have any suggestions on what I could change?

```
app.post('/authenticate',function(req,res){
conn.open(connString, function(err){
if(err) return console.log(err);

var loginID = req.body.LoginID,
    passWord = req.body.PassWord;

//-------------------------Security---------------------------
    // create random Word Arrays for key and Salt
    var key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    var iv  = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);

    // Encrypt Password using key and Salt. Changes every time but will always decrypt to same password.
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(passWord, key, { iv: iv }).toString();
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv }).toString();

    console.log(decrypted);

//-------------------------END Security------------------------    

conn.query("SELECT PassWord from pub.User WHERE LoginID ='" + loginID  + "'",function(err,data){

    if(err) return console.log(err);   
    res.json(data);

    setValue(data);

    function setValue(value) {
    someVar = value;
    }
        for(key in someVar) {
            if(someVar.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var value = someVar[key];
                console.log(value.PassWord);
                console.log(encrypted);

                    if(value.PassWord == encrypted)
                    {
                        console.log("pass");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("Fail");
                    }
            }
        }

        conn.close(function(){
        console.log('Login Complete');
        }); 
    }); // conn.query

}); //END conn.open(connString, function(err){
}); // END app.post('/authenticate'
```

Thank You,

Comment: You should be using something like bcrypt/pbkdf2/scrypt instead for passwords.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Why did you choose Cryptojs?, I think there are better alternatives, like Bcrypt (that is what I commonly use), they expose a function to compare the string directly with the hash value, and that's it.

Give it a try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Well i wasn't entirely sure what was better to use. I found more with cryptojs than i did bcrypt initially so i stuck with it. Thanks for the link! I'll give it a shot and see if this works better for me.

Comment: bcrypt is a salt library, not encryption

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. By using a randomly generated key/iv, your `encrypted` password string will always be different, even though it will `decrypt` to the same value. So, you won't be able to compare encrypted strings the way you are doing it.

I think the first question you should ask yourself is, do you really need to be able to decrypt your passwords once they are stored in the database? If not, you might be better off using a simple hash. You can use Node's built-in `Crypto` package for that -- and that is what I typically use to store hashed passwords. I have a few utility methods that I put into a `Utils` package, like:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * hashPassword creates a password hash from the supplied password and
 * salt values.
 *
 * @param {string} password
 * @param {string} salt
 * @returns {string}
 */
function hashPassword(password, salt) {
    let seed = sha1Base64(password, salt);
    return sha256Hex(seed);
}

/**
 * sha1Base64 returns a signature using the supplied string and key.
 *
 * @param {string} str
 * @param {string} key
 * @returns {string}
 */
function sha1Base64(str, key) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', key)
        .update(new Buffer(str, 'utf8'))
        .digest('base64');
}

/**
 * sha256Hex returns a string hash of the supplied data.
 *
 * @param {string|number|object} data
 * @returns {string}
 */
function sha256Hex(data) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256')
        .update(data)
        .digest('hex');
}
```

The `hashPassword` function will create a 64 character string of hex digits. You get the general idea of hashing the password to store it in the database and then hashing the user's password on submission of the login form. Same thing here, only this doesn't require any outside packages.

However, you will still need to use the same salt each time. You can assign a system-wide salt through an environment variable (more secure), keep one in the database either on a per-user or per-account basis (less secure), or put one in a config file somewhere (probably a bad idea). It really depends on what you are trying to protect as to how fanatical you have to be -- are you creating a login area for a personal blog or a consumer-facing website for Chase Bank? Just make sure your salt is sufficiently long and random. You can use a function to generate a random string of whatever length you want:

```js
/**
 * randomString returns a random alphanumeric string of the specified length.
 *
 * @param {number} [length]
 * @param {boolean} [special]
 * @returns {string}
 */
function randomString(length = 10, special = false) {
    let chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if (special) chars += '-_%!@#$^&*';
    let cLength = chars.length,
        sRandom = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sRandom += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * cLength)];
    }

    return sRandom;
}
```

For most of the stuff I've ever done, using a hash like this is sufficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It really cleared some things I was foggy about. I'll be looking into this later tonight so i can fully understand everything. Thanks again it really helped me out.